# bash regex multiple matches

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have a nice little `bash` script which parses a message for a regular expression and does something with the capture groups:

```
regex='\((Closes|Resolves):\s([0-9]+)\)'
msg='Fixed a problem (Closes: 1234), (Resolves: 5678)'

if [[ $msg =~ $regex ]] ; then
  action="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  issue="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  do_something $action $issue
fi
```

This works well for the first match, but if there are multiple matches `msg`, later matches are ignored.  Is there a way for me to loop through each match or is it time to start thinking of `python` or `perl`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not explicitly supported by built-in `bash` syntax, but it can be easily achieved with a little variable substitution and some recursion.

```
function do_something {
  echo $1 $2
}

function handlematches {
  regex='\((Closes|Resolves):\s([0-9]+)\)'
  msg=$1

  if [[ $msg =~ $regex ]] ; then
    action="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    issue="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    do_something "$action" "$issue"

    # Remove the first regex match and try again
    handlematches "${msg/${BASH_REMATCH[0]}/}"
  fi
}

message='Fixed a problem (Closes: 1234), (Resolves: 5678)'
handlematches "$message"
```

Output:

```
Closes 1234
Resolves 5678
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Stewart's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637905/116858), but using an iterative rather than recursive approach:

```bsh
regex='\((Closes|Resolves): ([0-9]+)\)'
msg='Fixed a problem (Closes: 1234), (Resolves: 5678)'

while [[ $msg =~ $regex ]]; do
        action=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        issue=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        do_something "$action" "$issue"

        msg=${msg/"${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"/}
done
```

This iterates over the string in `$msg` until the regular expression no longer matches.  In each iteration, the matching bit is remove using a `bash` parameter substitution.

If you want to hold on to the original `$msg`, then make a copy of it in another variable first.

With

```bsh
do_something () {
        printf 'action=%s, issue=%s\n' "$1" "$2"
}
```

this outputs

```
action=Closes, issue=1234
action=Resolves, issue=5678
```